# How to use "offset" when talking to a vendor?

Tags: word-usage, past-tense, irregular

I am having a problem with the word ***offset***. This is what I'm going to type to my vendor:

> If we do not receive your Statement of Account by 30 Mar '12, all payments will be "***offsetted***".

Is it OK to use *offsetted* in this sentence?

Comment: Past for "set" is "set".  Not "setted".

Comment: "Offsetted" isn't a word; the past and past participle of "offset" is "offset."

Comment: @GEdgar & upvoters See below: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/97347/14666

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about anybody else, but I would be confused I was told that all of my payments would be offset.  I think you should use a phrase or even an entire sentence to describe exactly what you are going to do.

I would generally be quite concerned over what would happen to all my payments, which sounds like it could represent a fair amount of money.

Comment: Steve, how would you like this post to be highlit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The past-tense of *offset* can be ***offsetted***, especially in certain domain specific usages such as in engineering and accounting.

[The-Conjugation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offset#English) online as well as [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offset#English) list *offsetted* as the past tense.

"It may be carried forward for a maximum of 2 years and **offsetted** against MCT." (Eric E. Rowley, ["The Fin. Sys. Today: Understanding Fin. Inf."](http://books.google.com/books?id=EMhRAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA140&dq=offsetted&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MI_uUN78H4zVkAWFmIH4Cw&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBjgU), 1987, p.140)

"In taking this account, the expenditure of each year should be **offsetted** against the rents and profits" ([SC of Appeals of Va., V34, p744](http://books.google.com/books?id=y4stAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA744&dq=offsetted&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MI_uUN78H4zVkAWFmIH4Cw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwADgU))

"When an entry is made in the factory ledger accounts at the general office, it is **offsetted** by an entry made in the general ledger account at the factory office." ([Khan, "Cost Acctg N Fin Mgmt 4 Ca Pcc", 2008, p.7-4,](http://books.google.com/books?id=48UzraCs95kC&pg=SA7-PA4&dq=offsetted&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MI_uUN78H4zVkAWFmIH4Cw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAzgU) )

Answer (score 0):

Offsetted is not the past tense of offset.  Offset is the past tense of offset, it is also the verb form and the noun.  It's worse than sheep.